# Can't access python global variable (really weird)

Tags: python, global

So here's a simplified version of what's going on

```
x = []

def test():
    return x

def init():
    x.append('blah')
```

The issue: The init() function is run in a separate file and updates the global variable x correctly. But after running the test() function, I will ALWAYS get a value of [] instead of ['blah']. But here's where it gets weird. If i were to run this function (whatever_file.py being the name of where these functions are stored):

```
x = []

def test():
    from whatever_file import x
    return x

def init():
    x.append('blah')
```

This works fine. I will get ['blah'] returned. I have tried putting global x in the init and test function with no avail as well. I have no clue what's going on

Any help?

Comment: As another side note, if I create a class and a static method within th eclass, the updated global variable is recognized fine. Just using a standalone function messes stuff up

Comment: Your variable is global in the MODULE only, is in not visible outside of it (that's why it works when you import). Global variables are generally a bad idea --- what are you trying to do?  If you feel you must, use the 'global' keyword.

Comment: So that's the thing. Having global x in both function still doesn't get my test() function to recognize the global variable. What's up with that?

Comment: I don't see 'global' anywhere in your code.

Comment: What I mean is I tried using global x in both functions apart from this as well but it didn't work

Comment: consider a single file a globe, so global will only make the variable available to the current file.  In python there is no universal() command.

Answer (score 4):

Python's globals aren't really global.  Each module has its own globals, so the variable you're storing isn't visible in the other module's globals.

To store a value in another module's namespace, just set the attribute on the module object directly:

```
import math

def store(x):
    math.x = x
```